# Pydantic: How do I use a keyword field name?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to model an API request in Pydantic. I have to model a field called "from". Since "from" is a keyword in python, Pydantic throws an error.

Model

```
class MyRequest(BaseModel):
    foo: str
    abc: int
    from: int
```

Error thrown by Pydantic

```
File "test.py", line 6
    from: int

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there to model this "from" field? Changing the parameter name is not an option.

Comment: my be because 'from' key word in python change it and see

Answer (score 21):

Use an [alias](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/):

```py
class MyRequest(BaseModel):
    foo: str
    abc: int
    from_field: int = Field(..., alias='from')
```

Comment: how should it be instantiated? `MyRequest(foo='a', abc=1, from=2)` still raises a `SyntaxError`, while using `from_field` instead of `from` will lead to a `pydantic.ValidationError`.

Comment: Have you tried `MyRequest(**{'foo': 'a', 'abc': 1, 'from': 2})`?